# Run PHP Script containing MySql commands 1 million times

Tags: php, mysql, curl, wordnet

I am working with WordNet MySql database. I have two database. The Wordnet Sql DB, and another database that is for inputting URLs. The second database, through Python and PHP, takes a URL, splits it up into words, and then associates the word with the URL. The main PHP method utilizes 3 other methods, all containing their own set of SQL commands.

ATM, I have a web interface, that allows you to input a URL, and then do the things I just mentioned. Which works fine I think. The problem is that I need to do this for about 1 million URLs. I tried creating a php for loop to just do call my main method that calls all the other methods which do the SQL commands, but does not work. It only does it for 2 urls. How do I do this to all 1 million URLs.

Let me know if I need to put up all my PHP/MySql Wordnet Up.

Can I do Curl Command for each of the URLs?, And if so, How can I do a curl request for Each row(individual URL)

Comment: "It only does it for 2 urls" Why? What happens then?

Comment: in the for loop, i have it echo the url being input, and it only shows 2 urls being input. I check the DB, and only 2 urls have been input. not sure why it stops.

Comment: well, then why don't you check the error log or step through the code with a debugger to find out? This could yield more useful insights into the problem.

Comment: Oh, I had searched for php debugging and most everything said use eclipse. I just found <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); thanks for the suggestion. Do you know of anything better? I actually found my problem by adding that to my file.

Comment: The commonly used IDEs (Netbeans, Eclipse, Zend Studio or PHPStorm) come with debuggers. I prefer PHPStorm. As an alternative, you can use phpdbg. Since you found your problem now: consider adding it to your question.

Comment: Is there in the URLs more transactions like ajax?